# Unsufficient scope when attempting to update video

Tags: php, dailymotion-api

I'm currently working on a project that allows staff to upload videos to DailyMotion via an admin interface without having to touch DailyMotion it self (the video's are embedded on our site but hosted on DM.)

Because of this, I am using `/file/upload` to generate a public upload URL and then using `/me/videos` to publish the video and set a few settings.

```
// Initiatlise and authenticate.
$api = new Dailymotion();
$api->setGrantType(
    Dailymotion::GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD, 
    'api_key', 
    'api_key_secret', 
    array(
        'write', 
        'delete', 
        'manage_videos'
    ), array(
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password'
    )
);

// Get public upload/progress urls.
$urls = $api->get('/file/upload');

// Upload result with video URL.
$upload_result = {
    acodec: "AAC",
    bitrate: 1248721,
    dimension: "1280x720",
    duration: 13504,
    format: "MPEG-4",
    hash: "...",
    name: "...",
    seal: "...",
    size: 2107842,
    streamable: "No",
    url: "...",
    vcodec: "AVC"
};

// Update video to set published etc.
$result = $api->post(
    '/me/videos',
    array(
        'url' => $upload_result->url,
        'title' => 'Some title',
        'publish' => true
    )
);
```

From the above, I am setting the `manage_videos` scope and it's still reporting back that I don't have the correct scope?

Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're passing the `manage_videos` scope and still get an error mentioning you don't have the correct scope, it must be due to an existing session.

One of the problems with OAuth 2.0 is that the specification doesn't offer any mechanism to upgrade the scope of an existing session. To add new scopes to an already existing session, you first need to call the `Dailymotion::logout()` method and start a new session with your new list of scopes (see the note mentioning this at https://developer.dailymotion.com/tools/sdks#sdk-php-authentication ).

Comment: Hi DailyMotion, thank you for getting back to me. I added $api->logout(); before setting my grant type and it failed, but seemed to come back with a different error afterwards. `This user is not a Dailymotion verified partner, the 'allow_embed' parameter is therefore not allowed.` - FYI, we are a partner with a verified domain? - Removing the parameter worked though :)

Comment: right this is a new issue. Are you sure the user authenticated is verified? if so, please report this issue with all details (code, user, etc ) at https://faq.dailymotion.com/hc/en-us/requests/new using the "api" tab, we'll check this issue.

Comment: Thanks DailyMotion - Everything is working for now, so not a major issue. If it becomes one, I'll report as suggested. Thanks again :)